# How to compute expected value of $X^3$ binomial random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

just studied probability generating functions, and I have studied that a probability of $X^k$ while X is $bin(n,p)$ can be calculated using some formula with probability generating functions that argue - $E[X(X-1)(X-2)...(X-k+1)]$ = the kth derivative of $G_X(1)$.

I know that -

$X^3 = X(X-1)(X-2) + 3X^2 - 2X$

$E[X^3] = E[X(X-1)(X-2)] + 3E[X^2] -2E[X]$

but I'm having trouble to understand how to compute precisely

$E[X(X-1)(X-2)]$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have $E[X(X-1)(X-2)] = G_X^{\prime\prime\prime}(1)$, where $G_X(z)$ is the pgf of $X$.

In your particular case the pgf of a $bin(n, p)$ random variable is $G_X(z) = (q + pz)^n$.  (Here $q = 1-p$, which is pretty much standard notation.)

So you can differentiate to get

$$G_X^\prime(z) = pn (q+pz)^{n-1}, G_X^{\prime\prime}(z) = (pn) (p(n-1)) (q+pz)^{n-2}, G_X^{\prime\prime\prime}(z) = (pn) (p(n-1)) (p(n-2)) (q+pz)^{n-3}.$$

Presumably you can take it from here, by plugging in $z = 1$ and simplifying.